# Aspose.Words MailMerge text object tagging in .Net

Tags: object, text, tagging, mailmerge, aspose.words

Anyone know how to tag text objects from Aspose.Words MailMerge, this is to be compatible with the PDF/UA standard. I would appreciate any code samples and/or links

Answer (score 0):

You should simply enable [PdfSaveOptions.ExportDocumentStructure](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.saving/pdfsaveoptions/properties/exportdocumentstructure) option. Aspose.Words exports PDF/UA compatible document structure.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i am using the PdfCompliance PdfA1a, so the structure should already be provided